# VS Code Debugger: Import error, no module named scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, vscode-debugger

I am able to run all the scrapy spiders on vs code without any error. But when I try to run the debugger, it raises an exception

```
No module named scrapy
```

I am on MacOS. I can properly run scrapy commands from the terminal as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your script from cmd in debug mode with

```sh
python -m debugpy --listen 5678 --wait-for-client ./__main__.py
```

*Make sure to install it using `python -m pip install debugpy`*

and then configure a `launch.json` file in the debugger to attach to the python script listening on port 5678

```json
{
  "name": "Python: Attach",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "attach",
  "connect": {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5678
  }
}
```

The complete file will look something like this

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After that set the breakpoints in your program and start the debugger from vscode

Also check if the version running during the debug is the same used normally, just create a blank file with the following content

```py
import sys

def main():
    print(sys.version)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the following will print something like

`3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) \n[GCC 8.4.0]`

Also check from the statusbar at the bottom of vscode if you have the right python version selected.

More on the first part [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_command-line-debugging)

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner. I lost you at the second step.  "and then configure the debugger to attach to the debug listening on port 5678". Do you mean I should add the above configuration in the launch.json configuration. It gives me a connection refused error when i try to run the vs code debugger using the above settings.

Comment: @KoijamK

You need to create a `launch.json` to debug your program. 

Also add the `--wait-for-client` before the name of the python script. I will update my answer.

Comment: This setup worked for me on Python 3.11.0. Just have to make sure to run the python command first, then start the debugger after. Thanks!